# Check whether private member variable is between certain range and if not adjust it

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to limit a private member variable `memVar` between 0 and 1. If the value of memVar is lower than 0 I would like it to be set to 0 and if its higher than 1 it should be set to 1. Therefore I would like to implement a function `limitMemVar` which is called each time when memVar is set or changed. The function is called within a template function of my class.

My class looks like this:

```
class Box {
   private:
      double memVar;     
   public: 
      // Member functions declaration
      void limitMemVar(double actValue);

      template <typename T>
      void DoSomething(const couble val);
};
```

And  my implemented function looks like this:

```
void Box::limitMemVar(double actValue) {

    if ( actValue< (double)0 )
    {
        this->memVar= (double)0;
    }
    else if ( actValue > (double)1 )
    {
        this->memVar= (double)1;
    }
}
```

The template function looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
void Box::DoSomething(const double val)
{
   //assign memVar the value of val
   memVar=val;
   //check memVar
   this->limitMemVar(this->memVar)
   // .... Do more Stuff
}
```

It is part of a larger software project. I can build and run it, but the results for all `memVar` is nAn.

But it works when i instead hard-code it directly into the template function like this:

```
template<typename T>
void Box::DoSomething(const double val)
{
   //assign memVar the value of val
   memVar=val;
   //check memVar
   if ( memVar< (double)0 )
    {
       memVar= (double)0;
    }
    else if ( memVar> (double)1 )
    {
        memVar= (double)1;
    }
   // .... Do more Stuff
}
```

What is wrong ?
I guess it is a pretty simple task but I am new to C++, so any help appreciated. 
Thanks for your time!

Comment: The question is, what is wrong? You don't show us any error?

Comment: What does your `limitMemVar` do when the value `actValue` is between 0 and 1?

Comment: As a side note, all those casts make the code really ugly. Can't you just compare to `0.0` and `1.0`? Actually, I'm pretty sure you can compare directly to 1 and 0.

Comment: ```memVar+=val``` does not do what the comment says, it does not assign val to memVar, but adds val to memVar.

Comment: `limitMemVar` doesn't look right to me. Either you assign actValue to memVar if it is in range (especially as this is a public member!) or you drop the parameter entirely, checking **`memvar`** being < 0 or > 1...

Comment: @RoQuOTriX I edited my question to give a bit more clarification.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

[`std::clamp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Probably worth noting that it's not available prior to C++17.

Comment: True. You probably want to use `std::min(std::max(myvalue, 0.0), 1.0)` with pre-c++17 compilers.

Comment: Can't use it, as I am using an older C++